# Button style - ignore css

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to ignore Google CSS styling when creating a particular button ? Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pc1nqbqe/2/), where I want to change my button width to 5 px, which is ignored because of the external CSS

HTML:

```
<input type="submit">
```

CSS:

```
input[type="submit"] {
height: 25px;
width: 5px;
border: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: And by Google CSS styling I mean https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you load your CSS after the google stylesheet, you can overwrite the styles with the selector you're using. And google applies `min-width: 72px` which you'll need to overwrite if you want the width to be `5px`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<style>
input[type="submit"] {
    height: 25px;
    width: 5px;
    border: 2px dotted red;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: green;
    color: white;
    min-width: 0;
}
</style>
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: Thanks Michael ! Didn't know about the load order importance. You saved my day

Answer (score 1):

Use the following CSS:

```
input[type="submit"] {
  width: 5px;
  min-width: 5px;
}
```

Google CSS contains a minimum width of 72 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael said, load your CSS stylesheet after the Google CSS and it will over right it. Or, you can add `min-width: 5px;` and `max-width: 5px;` to your button CSS and it will do the same job.

```html
<style>
input[type="submit"] {
    height: 25px;
    min-width: 5px;
    max-width: 5px;
    border: 2px dotted red;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: green;
    color: white;
    min-width: 0;
}
</style>
<input type="submit">
```